# PSQL: Concatenate a value with LIKE in stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to concatenate a variable using the `LIKE` statement and for some reason it only finds values where the word to search is at the end of the text variable.

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 and this is stored in a function (stored procedure)

considering in this example:

**a.key1** is "HELLO"

**a_text** is "I SAY HELLO TO THE WORLD"

Code:

```
SELECT count(1), a.key1, a.active, a.campkeydbid
    FROM campkeydb a
WHERE a_text LIKE '%'|| a.key1 ||'%'
   GROUP BY a.key1, a.active, a.campkeydbid
INTO a_count, a_campaignkey, a_active, a_campkeydbid;
```

In this stored procedure it will NOT return the values; it will not find the word "HELLO"?

It will ONLY return the values if **a_text** contains "I SAY HELLO"

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?  It seems that it is correct as I am concatenating a **%** on both sides of the variable **a.key1**.

Comment: Are you certain that `a.key1` is exactly `'HELLO'` rather than `' HELLO'` or something similar? Try a quick `select '-' || key1 || '-' from campkeydb` to see if you have stray spaces.

Comment: Or perhaps there's something wrong with the `a_text` value? Have you tried running this query with `a_text` *replaced* with the string itself?

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I did some quick selects and no spaces, but I also added trim on my JAVA to send "clean" info ! thanks... it was solved by adding "AND a.deleted = false", I realized that there were more rows but were marked deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the position string function instead of like.  Here is a sample query using a table of the regions and departments of France.  I'll try and find all the departments that have a name that includes the region name.

```
select r.name as region, d.name as deprtment, position( r.name in d.name) as pos
from regions r
join departments d on d.region = r.code
where position( r.name in d.name) != 0
and r.name != d.name;
```

The results are

```
region  department     pos
"Corse" "Corse-du-Sud"  1
"Corse" "Haute-Corse"   7
```

I added the pos column to show that strings are indexed from 1, not 0.  I tried the same thing with 'like' (both queries have the same query plan and should give the same performance):

```
select r.name as region, d.name as deprtment, position( r.name in d.name) as pos
from regions r
join departments d on d.region = r.code
where d.name like '%' || r.name || '%'
and r.name != d.name;
```

I like the appearance of the first query, but they both do the same thing.  So your logic seems correct, so this seems like a typo in a string.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses and help... I used both select statements and you are right the logic was correct (thank you for making sure I was not going insane) looking at my data, I saw that there were more rows with the same key but they were marked "deleted" so I added (AND a.deleted = FALSE) and this solved the problem... it seems that it is always human error...  thanks again for your time and help!!